# Please find enclosed...?

Tags: grammar, business-language, email

I ran into a phrase that does not make sense to me. It reads:
*We are always pleased to have new subscribers, and I am certain you will be delighted with the upcoming season. Please **find enclosed the tickets** for the five plays for this season.*

By Googling, I discovered such phrase is commonly used in business emails, albeit one that is frowned upon by grammarians. But "find enclosed the tickets" sounds odd and ridiculous to me. I believe the sentence would be better as "find the enclosed tickets."

Could someone explain the reasoning behind the seemingly odd structure of the phrase?

Thank you.

Comment: I actually agree that, syntactically, it's at least awkward, if not outright wrong. I would normally write this "Please find the tickets enclosed." (This is the first time I've seen the exact phrasing you give.) If I were forced to keep your word order, I would resort to using punctuation: "Please find (enclosed) the ticket." That still looks odd, but I can make better sense of the syntax.

Comment: I agree that this question is a duplicate of the question that Edwin Ashworth mentions above. However, I am hesitant to close this one, given that the earlier question was closed long ago (and wrongly, in my opinion) as more appropriate for English Language Learners, and given that it has even drawn one vote for deletion. I recommend reopening that question and then closing this one as a duplicate of it. Among other things, the earlier question has drawn a very interesting and detailed answer regarding the logic of the construction—one that I hope San Kim (the poster here) will read.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a conventional way of letting the recipient of your letter know that you are enclosing another document with it. 'X is enclosed, so please look for it'. Today it's considered old-fashioned; it's better just to put 'I enclose X'.

Comment: So it is old-fashioned. I see. Thank you for your succinct answer!